# Convert `List<string>` to comma-separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a fast way to convert `List<string>` to a comma-separated `string` in C#?

I do it like this but Maybe there is a faster or more efficient way?

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("one");
ls.Add("two");
string type = string.Join(",", ls.ToArray());
```

PS: Searched on this site but most solutions are for Java or Python

Comment: Nope, you're doing it right. Although I don't think you need to do `ToArray()`.

Comment: Faster to write or faster to execute?

Comment: Both :), But apparently it is not possible

Comment: @Yuck It is needed to convert to `string[]` (Because I don't use `.NET 4`)

Comment: @Ozkan You should probably tag your question for the framework version you're working against then. I think you'll find most answers will assume you're using the latest release.

Comment: Just use Select with String.Join like this:
string type = String.Join(",", ls.Select(s => s).ToArray());

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In .NET 4 you don't need the `ToArray()` call - [`string.Join` is overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) to accept `IEnumerable<T>` or just `IEnumerable<string>`.

There are potentially more efficient ways of doing it before .NET 4, but do you really need them? Is this actually a bottleneck in your code?

You *could* iterate over the list, work out the final size, allocate a `StringBuilder` of exactly the right size, then do the join yourself. That would avoid the extra array being built for little reason - but it wouldn't save much time and it would be a *lot* more code.

Comment: string.Join(",",myList )

Answer (score 20):

To expand on Jon Skeets answer the code for this in `.Net 4` is:

```
string myCommaSeperatedString = string.Join(",",ls);
```

Answer (score 15):

The following will result in a comma separated list. Be sure to include a using statement for `System.Linq`

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("one");
ls.Add("two");
string type = ls.Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y);
```

will yield one,two

if you need a space after the comma, simply change the last line to `string type = ls.Aggregate((x,y) => x + ", " + y);`

Comment: @Ozkan Please test it, and let us know.

Comment: actually, I hadn't checked. With only the two items in the List, no, they are equally as fast, but exploding it to 100,000 items, the Aggregate actually is far slower than string.Join. Good to know I guess. I've preferred Aggregate in the past, but I think I'll be moving to string.Join in the future

Comment: And, I found this throws an exception if the list is empty

Answer (score 4):

Follow this:

```
       List<string> name = new List<string>();   

        name.Add("Latif");

        name.Add("Ram");

        name.Add("Adam");
        string nameOfString = (string.Join(",", name.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Comment: This can be simplified further. The ToArray and ToString are not necessary, and the following works: `String nameOfString = String.Join(",", name.Select(x => x));`

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<string> listStrings = new List<string>(){ "C#", "Asp.Net", "SQL Server", "PHP", "Angular"};
   string CommaSeparateString = GenerateCommaSeparateStringFromList(listStrings);
   Console.Write(CommaSeparateString);
   Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string GenerateCommaSeparateStringFromList(List<string> listStrings)
{
   return String.Join(",", listStrings);  
}
```

[Convert a list of string to comma separated string C#.](http://www.codesolution.org/convert-a-list-of-string-to-comma-separated-string-c/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I'd prefer to see if I was maintaining your code.  If you manage to find a faster solution, it's going to be very esoteric, and you should really bury it inside of a method that describes what it does.

(does it still work without the ToArray)?

Comment: I can do `string.Join` only on `Array`'s of `strings`. So it is necessary (because I don't use `.NET 4`